# Obtain date without timestamp in DB2

Tags: db2

Please pardon my ignorance if I have missed any documentation/solution for the same. But I searched the web and could not find an answer.

I have a simple question. In the DB2 table,I have a column of type date and the with data of format 04/25/2013 12:00:00AM . When I query the DB2 database, I want to obtain just the date and not the timestamp i.e to obtain "04/25/2013" and not "04/25/2013 12:00:00AM". I tried DATE(column name) and just gave back the complete value including the time stamp.

Comment: Which platform edition of DB2 (IBM i, LUW, or z/OS) are you using, and what version?  What type of session do you have that is giving you this result?

Comment: Agreed, `DATE()` should have given you the results you expect.  Also, the `DATE` type in DB2 doesn't have a time value in it, which would normally mean it's a `TIMESTAMP`.  (As a side note, most RDBMSs don't store date/time values in a format - they use a separate internal representation that gets translated at display time.)

Comment: please provide us with the table definition! I cannot believe that your column is of type DATE. or your SELECT is casting the result to a timestamp!

Comment: Its  IBM z/OS DB2. The column is of type Date and I am not sure why even the date(column name) method returns date and time.I read a bit and I got to know that somehow I am getting a timestamp

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a TIMESTAMP and not a DATE column. If it is indeed a TIMESTAMP column try this:

```
select varchar_format(current timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY') from sysibm.sysdummy1 ;
```

Just replace the current timestamp in the above example with your column and sysibm.sysdummy1 with your table.

The good thing about varchar_format is that it lets you easily format the timestamp. Just change the 'MM/DD/YYYY' part to 'YYYY.MM.DD' to get a format like '2017.08.18'.